# MySQL using CPU after cancelling slow query

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, process

I had to cancel a very slow running query after it ran for a few days without completing on my Ubuntu server.
Since then MySQL has been persistently running a process which is using 25-45% of the CPU at any given time. The process just restarts when attempting to kill it.
Has anyone observed this issue before and know how to fix it?

Comment: could be the db engine should remove temporary table or index do to the previous long query...

Comment: If this was a query that was modifying data, then you now have a *runaway rollback* on your hands; the server made changes, but kept track of the former data, and is now in the process of permanently reverting everything to the way it was, undoing the changes.  For this reason, your best course is to leave it alone.  It should eventually finish.  Or, you can [force it to stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956693/how-to-stop-rollback-in-progress/24957055#24957055) but that's not the necessarily the best or safest course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop rollback in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956693/how-to-stop-rollback-in-progress/24957055#24957055).

Comment: Ah thanks guys that definitely gives me much more to go on.  I'm going to do more research on rollbacks then and in the meantime I'll let it go on.